# Microsoft Excel 2010 Plugin problems

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

In our lab environments, we are having some trouble getting the analysis toolpak enabled and available on the data tab in the ribbon. Originally, the add-in is not checked in add-ins, so we check it and nothing appears in data tab. All of the files necessary are sitting in the library folder. Completely uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't work either. I have all of the office tools, and add-ins set to "Run on my computer". Can someone please help?

On a side note, it also seems like my other add-ins don't work either.

I believe I am also seeing plug-ins not working in Word. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked the Add-ins settings in the Trust Center? You may have all add-ins disabled there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure plugins are allowed in the trust center

In Excel, click File and Options

Then in left side column, click Trust Center (at bottom)

Then, in the new window, check out Add-ins. It may be disabled or you may require the addin to be signed first...

Answer (score 0):

I have actually been racking my brain over this a while, and I must've looked at this a dozen times, but I believe I found my answer. I had checked all of everything Dave Rook recommended, and it was fine. In the process of looking at that checked out my GPOs applied to the machines.

I had "Disable VBA for Office applications" set to "Enabled". Path is: Computer\Policies\Administrative Templates\Microsoft Office 2010(Machine)\Security Settings.

Changed it to disabled. Analysis toolpak is now back.

I appreciate the help and they were good suggestions.